# Extract Integer from a datatype

Tags: haskell, syntax

I know i can do something like this to get an integer out of a datatype:

```
[x | (PhoneNo x) <- [PhoneNo 1234]]
```

where PhoneNo is defined as:

```
data PhoneNo = PhoneNo Integer deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

However this is better for lists. How can I extract the integer of a single PhoneNo instance?

Comment: By giving it a record field `newtype PhoneNo = PhoneNo { getPhoneNo :: Integer }` the compiler generates a function equivalent to `getPhoneNo :: PhoneNo -> Integer; getPhoneNo (PhoneNo n) = n`.

Answer (score 5):

Pattern matching is the canonical mechanism to deconstruct algebraic data types. You are already using it in your example: `PhoneNo x` is a *pattern* against which the *value* `PhoneNo 1234` is matched, binding `x` to `1234` in the head of the list comprehension (here simply `x`).

Pattern matching happens a number of places in Haskell, most notably in function definitions:

```hs
extract :: PhoneNo -> Integer
extract (PhoneNo x) = x
```

Alternatively, you can match values against patterns in `let`, `where` and `case` expressions:

```hs
let (PhoneNo x) = PhoneNo 1234 in ... x ...

myFunction = ... x ...
   where
     (PhoneNo x) = PhoneNo 1234

case PhoneNo 1234 of
  PhoneNo x -> .... x ...
```

Comment: I wouldn't say pattern matchin is “the” canonical way. For sum types yes, but for records it tends to be much more convenient to use record-field accessors (or lenses). It also makes the code more robust to changes in the data structure.

Comment: I agree with justkris that it is the canonical way. Record field accessors are implemented with pattern matching.

Comment: I stand by the canonicity of pattern matching. How are those accessors and lenses defined? ;)